# IndexError: list index out of range in an array

Tags: python, list

I have got a variable named featureset. When it is printed, the values are like following.

```
>>> featuresets[:2]

[({'contains2(left)': True, 'contains2(this)': True, 'contains2(now)': True, 'contains2(with)': True, 'contains1(now)': False, 'contains2(name)': True, 'contains2(gay)': True, 'contains2(im)': True}, 'Statement'), ({'contains2(p)': True, 'contains1(:)': False, 'contains2(:)': True}, 'Emotion')]
```

I need to filter the label(class variable) to an array in python.

Here is the code that I have written

```
referenceSets=[]
testSets=[]

for i, (features, label) in enumerate(featuresets):
    referenceSets[i].append(label)
    predicted = classifier.classify(features)
    testSets[i].append(label)
```

but I'm getting the error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 2, in <module>
  referenceSets[i].append(label)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone please mention what my problem here is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`referenceSets` is initialized to an empty list on the first line. When you attempt to access `referenceSets[i]`, for any `i`, that index won't exist in the list.

It's unclear what the role of `i` is and what you're trying to accomplish with it. Perhaps you mean to initialize `referenceSets` to a list of lists? This will allow you to index into `referenceSets` with `i` as your code is currently doing.

```
referenceSets = [[] for _ in xrange(len(featuresets))]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `referenceSets` is an empty list. So when you enter the loop the first statement is `referenceSets[i]` (with `i=0`) but since there are no elements in the list you get the `IndexError`:

```
>>> referenceSets = []
>>> referenceSets[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```